# Issue using View()->Composer() in AppServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to pass data to a view using the boot method in the `AppServiceProvider`, and have followed the steps outlined in one of the Laracast fundamentals videos. However, I am getting an error in my controller when trying to use this variable.

In my AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('home', function($view){
        $view->with('current', Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first());
    });
}
```

So this should pass the data to my home view as far as I understand, so that I don't need to keep referencing it in all the methods I have in the controller for that view. I then have a homeController with the following method:

```
public function index()
{
    //Get user
    $user = Auth::user();

    //OMDB API setup - Get Movie name, remove spaces, add into API request
    $movie_one = str_replace(" ", "+", $current->movie_one);


    $movie_two = str_replace(" ", "+", $current->movie_two);

    return view('home', compact(array('user')));

}
```

Previously I was adding a variable called `current` in this method to get an entry from my `Post` table, but wanted to add it to the `AppServiceProvider` as I will have to re-declare it in other methods as well. The issue I have is that I try to use the `$current` object again in this method, but it isn't available to it? I get the following error:

```
ErrorException in homeController.php line 30:
```

Undefined variable: current

What can I do here? Can I pass that data from to a controller as well as the home view? Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you written inside the `boot` method, will only be accessible inside home view, if you want to access the `Post object` inside controller too, you have to follow this, through this you can access your `Post` object in controller, as will as view.

```
app()->singleton('current',function($app){
    return Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
});
```

So in your code, you can access the `Post` object like this,

```
$post_obj = App::make('current');
$post_obj->movie_two;
```

or directly

```
App::make('current')->movie_two;
```